# how to add a colorbar to a plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar

i have a dataframe with two columns
The one is dif and the other is sza

i have made the following scatter plot

```
x = df['sza']

y = df['dif']

# Calculate the point density

xy = np.vstack([x,y])

z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

what i want to do is to add a colorbar that will indicate the point density z that is shown in the plot

how can i do that ?

Comment: Have you checked out [matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html)?

Comment: Did you try calling `plt.colorbar()` after `ax.scatter(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same question and I figure it out how to do.

To create the color bar, you have to setup the ScalarMappable.

In your case,

```
#import cm
from matplotlib import cm
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100)
#set the ScalarMappable to viridis
cb = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='viridis')
fig.colorbar(cb, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

This should work. For more detials please read [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html).

And I would suggest to also align the scale of the colorbar with your scatter.

To do this, change these two lines.

```
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100)
cb = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='viridis', norm=sc.norm)
```